# Calling function on load of function

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to use my old code in my new application. I have the following problem.

I need to call something similar to `this.Loaded += OnLoaded` in my new code. But I cannot because I don't have `: Page` in my class.

The old code:

```
    public sealed partial class VotePage : Page
    {
        public VotePage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            // This will call the OnLoaded function
            this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
        }
```

Old code (OnLoaded function):

```
        public async void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var response = await start();

            dynamic dynJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);

            foreach (var item in dynJson)
            {
                Object votedGame = localSettings.Values[item.slug.ToString()];
                string voted = "Collapsed";
                string btnVoted = "VOTE";
                bool btnEnabled = true;

                if(votedGame != null)
                {
                    voted = "Visible";
                    btnVoted = "VOTED!";
                    btnEnabled = false;
                }

                listofGames.Add(new Games { Title = item.name, Votes = item.votes, Slug = item.slug, Voted = voted, BtnVoted = btnVoted, BtnEnabled = btnEnabled });
            }

            gamesList.ItemsSource = listofGames;
        }
```

New code:

```
    public class GamesList
    {
        public List<Game> Games { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }

        public GamesList(String databaseName)
        {
            Name = databaseName;

            // This won't work because there is no await.
            Games = DataService.GetGames;
        }
```

DataService.GetGames function:

```
        public async Task<List<Game>> GetGames()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("GET for games.");

            var response = await start();

            dynamic dynJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);

            foreach (var item in dynJson)
            {
                Object votedGame = localSettings.Values[item.slug.ToString()];
                string voted = "Collapsed";
                string btnVoted = "VOTE";
                bool btnEnabled = true;

                if (votedGame != null)
                {
                    voted = "Visible";
                    btnVoted = "VOTED!";
                    btnEnabled = false;
                }

                listofGames.Add(new Game { Title = item.name, Votes = item.votes, Slug = item.slug, Voted = voted, BtnVoted = btnVoted, BtnEnabled = btnEnabled });
            }

            return new List<Game>();
        }
```

Comment: Just put it in the constructor or call it manually from wherever appropriate in your case. OnLoaded is only important for UIElements/FrameworkElements because sometimes you need to make sure everything is loaded. If you don't have any child elements / visualtree / Bindings - why wait?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer It's in the constructor isn't it?

Comment: Maybe some information from [Stephen Cleary's blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html) will be helpfull.

Comment: @Chris In the constructor you wire up the event `Loaded`. So as soon as the Page is loaded (all Elements initialized and loaded too), the page fires the `Loaded` event and **then** OnLoaded is executed. My suggestion: replace `this.Loaded += OnLoaded;` with the code that is currently in your `OnLoaded` method (or remove the parameters and call it).

Comment: Your question is asking how to replace what you believe used to be the solution to your problem. However, you never really asked about your problem, or even identified, what problem you are trying to solve. You'll get a lot better results if you ask about your problem (not your proposed solution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on where, when and how the GamesList class is initialized you could give it a static creation method as suggested in the blog post linked by @Romasz:

```
public sealed class GamesList
{
    public List<Game> Games { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }

    private GamesList(String databaseName)
    {
        Name = databaseName;
    }

    public static async Task<GamesList> Create(string databaseName)
    {
        GamesList instance = new GamesList(databaseName);
        instance.Games = await DataService.GetGames();
        return instance
    }

    ...
}
```

You will then use the factory method to create an instance of and initialize the class asynchronously:

```
public VotePage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
}

public async void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataContext = await GamesList.Create("database name...");
}
```

Comment: First of all, sorry for the delayed answer. This unfortunately will not work because I cannot use `this.Loaded` anymore. I'm not using `: Page` anymore. I used it in my old code, which I changed to use MVVM

Comment: You still need to set the DataContext of the view somewhere. You don't necessarily have to do this in the Loaded event handler.

Comment: right so it now gives me the error that the `await` can only be used inside a `async` method

Comment: Of course the method in which you call and await the *asynchronous* factory method must be marked as async.

Comment: so I'm guessing that you forgot to add `async` to the `Create()` method then?